# Concatenate Two Fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Sales Invoice #, Invoice Date for each Product. I want to only show unique order per Product. I know Select distinct will pick only unique Invoices# and Invoice Date. Please show me how I can concatenate these two fields to show Unique Order Per Product.

eg:

```
Sales Invoice # | Invoice Date | Products                                       
  2122          | 9/24/2019    | A           
  2123          | 9/25/2019    | A                                           
  2122          | 9/24/2019    | A    
  2124          | 9/25/2019    | B 
  2125          | 9/25/2019    | B  
  2125          | 9/25/2019    | B
```

I want output which shows two columns only,

```
# of Orders  | Products       
           2 |A
           2 |B
```

I am new to SQL please tell me the query to merge Sales # and Invoice Date as Orders, as I want to visualize this in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select product, count(distinct sales_invoice_id)
from t
group by product;
```

Comment: Don't we need to consider about Invoice Date ?

Comment: @S.Y.K.J . . . "I want to only show unique order per Product."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's answer,

I suggest you do `"alter table"` and set unique key for `Sales Invoice #` ;

this way you won't have unnecessary duplicates in your table.

then

```
select * where product='B'
```

give you same number of rows as # of Orders of `B`.